# How to access variables and methods of objects within an array [resolved]

Tags: javascript

So I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class Car {

    constructor(name, pos) {

        this.carName = name;
        this.carPos = pos;
        
    }

}
```

I then end up creating an array of objects using this class as so:

```
newCar = new Car("Fusion","100 100");
let carManifest = [newCar]
```

I later in my code go on to `carManifest.push()` several other `Car` objects into the array, building it up. Eventually I run into a for loop such that:

```
for (index = 0; index < carManifest.length; index++) {
if(carManifest[index].carName === 'Honda')
    <Do Stuff>
}
```

Whenever I go to access `carManifest[index].carName` I get "undefined". I also had a get method within the object for the same variable, but using that in this context wouldn't even compile. I am aware that the array itself does not have these variables, but as far as I'm aware there is no way to declare an array to be of a specific class in JS like you can in Java and C.

Could anyone help me out? I am new to JS and have been stumped on this for the past hour. I will be glad to update this if there is not enough info. Thanks!

Note: Not sure if it matters but I am using Node.js

Comment: You have not sharing enough information. I've created a code based on information you've provided and clearly it's working totally fine. https://jsbin.com/betokigoni/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
let carManifest = [newCar]
```

to push item  to array as

```
carManifest.push(newCar);
```

```js
/*
function Car (name, pos) {
   this.carName = name;
   this.carPos = pos;    
}
*/
class Car {
    constructor(name, pos) {
        this.carName = name;
        this.carPos = pos;    
    }
}
newCar = new Car("Fusion","100 100");
let carManifest = [];
carManifest.push(newCar);

for (index = 0; index < carManifest.length; index++) {
if(carManifest[index].carName === 'Fusion'){
    console.log(carManifest[index].carName);
}
}
```

Comment: Why the need to declare an empty array? He should be able to just combine your two line of code into `let carManifest = [newCar]`

Comment: It turns out I simply forgot to capitalize the "N" in .carName hahaha. My lack of knowledge of JS sent me wayyyy off the trail. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing other variables or objects into the same array? There is nothing wrong with the code examples you're showing, you are able to access the variables of the objects this way. You'll have to show more code, where exactly are you getting undefined?